# Can you help me in understanding the bold part of the text?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, philosophy

Philosophy involves the mind turning upon itself and becoming explicitly aware of the modes of its own action, **which will have been in operation for some time before their philosophical reappropriation**.

what does author mean by "philosophical reappropriation"?

Answer (score 1):

Here the term philosophical reappropriation is used to define the moment when one consciously starts to look at his own thoughts and actions from a philosophical perspective. These thoughts/actions may have been in operation for quite some time although in a sub-conscious manner but now the person has decided to view these thoughts through a philosophical lens.